# Mac Powerpoint 2011 "play" presentation w/out full screen?

Tags: fullscreen, ms-office

I'm trying to play a presentation with Powerpoint without seeing it in full screen.  (my goal is to take notes on the presentation in a separate window/app).

Any ideas how to do this?  I want to be able to view the animations/transitions, which I don't get when viewing the powerpoint in edit mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured it out: use "Set Up Show" on the ribbon (or in the Slide Show menu), which has an option for "Browse by an individual (window)"

Hope that helps someone else :)